# Ceramic knives for boning?

Tags: knives, ceramic

I have read that one shouldn't use ceramic knives for cutting THROUGH bones, but how about for cutting AROUND bones? Examples would include cutting breasts off a chicken, carving around bones in steaks, etc. So the knife would probably come into occasional contact with a bone, but not with any serious amount of force.

Comment: Boning/fillet knives are typically flexible ... the exact opposite of ceramic.

Comment: Some aren't flexible (Honesuki/Garasuki/Deba), but they are typically not made of ceramic (though a ceramic deba exists).

Answer (score 5):

the problem with ceramic knives and bones is that they are incredibly brittle. Any slip into bone can cause chips in your blade so I would just not use them when bones are involved.

Answer (score 1):

Save your ceramics for fruits and vegetables.  Warnings are not limited to THROUGH bones.  For me a meat cuts fine with metal.

Comment: I'd even keep thinner ceramics clear of peach pits :)

Answer (score 0):

I would agree, a ceramic knife would not be the best knife for de-boning.  They were not intended to be used for this purpose.  The size, shape and weight are not suitable for de-bone most proteins.  I believe in the long run you would damage the knife.

Some bones, say pork or beef bones are harder, and if you hit them too hard with a ceramic knife, it could damage the edge.  Also some techniques require you to hit and break a bone to remove the meat from the bone.  A ceramic knife would probably shatter from the repeated impact.